# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code when archive app in xcode v 13.1

Tags: flutter, xcode

```
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/sereyvongthorn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-corqdinyzjasmidrvlqssijkobia/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-16A3BD1D6245A374368C41CD.sh (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    cd /Users/sereyvongthorn/Documents/Study/flutter/jks_admin_app/ios
    /bin/sh -c /Users/sereyvongthorn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-corqdinyzjasmidrvlqssijkobia/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-16A3BD1D6245A374368C41CD.sh

mkdir -p /Users/sereyvongthorn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-corqdinyzjasmidrvlqssijkobia/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks
Symlinked...
readlink: illegal option -- f
usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I already run flutter clean and clean build

Answer (score 3):

try to replace readlink -f with readlink in your framework.sh file

Comment: Yes, After 1 1\2 days spend on this issue . this answer is worked for me . Thank you @jennifer Sashi

Comment: Saved my life after hrs of being lost.

Comment: Where is framework.sh file?

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs because Cocoapods version 1.12.1 introduced the '**-f**' option in '**readlink**', causing it to fail during the Xcode v13 build.

To resolve this, you can downgrade your Cocoapods version to 1.12.0 using the following steps:

Run the following command to uninstall Cocoapods:

> sudo gem uninstall cocoapods

After uninstallation is complete, install Cocoapods version 1.12.0 using the following command:

> sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.12.0

Please note that you need to run these commands with administrative privileges using sudo in order to uninstall and install gems globally.